# Why is logstash not running after sending mail alerting

Tags: ruby, logstash

After running `logstash` to send e-mails, one of the messages has been blocked. So the `logstash` shows me this error:

> [2017-08-30T09:29:35,862][ERROR][logstash.shutdownwatcher ] The shutdown process appears to be stalled due to busy or blocked plugins. Check the logs for more information

And I can't send emails anymore.